# Whatsminer event code E011

Tags: mining-hardware, cgminer

I have a whatsminer M3 working for the past 2 months with no problems at all, but yesterday it started acting strange since it is restarting every 15 minutes, all temperatures are fine between 80 to 85deg celsius, and I noticed that there is an event with the following data

```
Event: code E011
Event cause: Slot-0 Zero HS 1620 seconds
Event action: Zero HS warning
Event count: 3
Event source: System-monitor
```

I have searched everywhere but I couldn’t find anything, I also contacted Pangolinminer to no avail.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in anvance

Charles

Comment: i have the same problem
did you find anything about this problem on M3?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Whatsminer models aren't as common as some miners you probably will have to contact the whatsminerd company and ask them.